# Xamarin.Forms.Maps nested inside a ScrollView. Map not usable since ScrollView is intercepting events

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Xamarin Android.

I have searched and tried many answers from other threads but can not get it to work.

I have been trying to use RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true); to stop my parent ScrollView from absorbing the Touch Events and allow panning on the MapView thats nested inside it but not successful.

Here is what I have done so far in my Maps Customer Renderer for Android

```
private IViewParent _scrolLView;

    private IViewParent GetParentScrollView(IViewParent parent)
    {
        if (parent is ScrollViewRenderer)
            return parent;
        return GetParentScrollView(parent.Parent);
    }

    public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        GetParentScrollView(Parent).RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
    }
```

But when I try to pan on the Map, the scroll view still intercepts and scrolls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent** is called when a child does not want this parent and its ancestors to intercept   touch events .

Try to change `GetParentScrollView(Parent)` to `this` , it works on my side .

```
 public override bool DispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        this.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return base.DispatchTouchEvent(e);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can add InputTransparent="True" in your scroolview attribut on xaml.
And it's works

Comment: This is not what the question is. The requirement is both scrollview and Map need to work at the same time.

Comment: Worked for me:

Scrollview : SKCanvasView

Comment: yes, this solution works when you have a map in a scrollview